# SSRS Double row headers and data display for printing

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

** I'm using SSRS2008 R2

I have a report that the users would like to see in a printable pdf.

Problem is there are several columns, potentially too many to fit on a printed 8.5x11 paper.

One of the concepts they suggested was a stacked header/data display, like breaking the columns into 2 rows, so 2 rows of data (for John and Bill) would look like this:

```
NAME          START_DATE         STATE        COMPANY
     ACCOUNT            BALANCE        END_DATE
-------------------------------------------------------
John          1/20/2016          NY           GE
     10076               $100.00       2/20/2016
-------------------------------------------------------
Bill          5/13/2016          MA           Netflix
     00013               $150.00       12/31/2016
-------------------------------------------------------
```

This leads me to 2 questions:

1. Is there a way to do this with a tablix?
2. AND/OR in addition, is there a way to set a default property on the report so when the report is exported to pdf and to print, that it defaults to fit all columns on one page (therefor shrinking the font size to fit on page?)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that cares - Apparently this can easily be achieved by dragging a Tablix onto the work area, right clicking the header row, adding a new row underneath (basically becomes header row 2), then do the same thing to the details row - however make sure to insert row - Inside group.  That allows you to have stacked header and data rows and you can copy / paste headers and row values in whichever row you'd prefer.

Answer (score 0):

it will work if you make all the columns on the same height not unequal. If all the columns has same height, then while exporting to pdf/excel and print it will come in the same page.